# PyQt Runtime Error of QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt, runtime-error, qcombobox, qtreewidgetitem

I'm trying to avoid the well-known PyQt Runtime Error when the underlying C/C++ object is deleted:

http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-April/022809.html

[PyQt4 - "RuntimeError: underlying C/C object has been deleted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213914/pyqt4-runtimeerror-underlying-c-c-object-has-been-deleted)

[PyQt4 nested classes - "RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051090/pyqt4-nested-classes-runtimeerror-underlying-c-c-object-has-been-deleted)

[PyQt: RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object has been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914960/pyqt-runtimeerror-wrapped-c-c-object-has-been-deleted)

Every one of my subclasses calls the `super()` method and therefore the base classes are properly constructed.

Still, I get this error and am wondering if it is due to the fact that I'm adding a `QComboBox` widget to a `QTreeWidgetItem` (using the `setItemWidget()` method of a `QTreeWidget`) but I cannot set the parent as the `QTreeWidgetItem` that contains it. When I try, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: QComboBox(QWidget parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QTreeWidgetItem'
```

Of course, I can either omit the parent in the constructor or pass the `QTreeWidget` as the parent, but I think I need to reference the correct parent.

I have subclassed the `QComboBox` and in my subclass it runs some basic operations on the `QTreeWidget`, but as soon as I enter the methods of my subclassed `QComboBox`, the underlying C object for the parent `QTreeWidgetItem` containing the `QComboBox` is deleted (which is why I'm thinking its something to do with setting the parent of the `QComboBox`).

I understand 9 times out of 10 the runtime error is due to not constructing the base class. But with that ruled out, how else can the error occur? Could it be due to not referencing the correct parent?

**EDIT**

I'm using the QComboBox to signal when a new combobox selection was made. Upon a new selection, it adds that selected value to a PyXB XML node. Interestingly, this issue only occurs if I append the value to the PyXB class binding storing the information permanently in an XML file. In otherwords, if that part of the code doesn't run I dont get the error - its only when the code runs the PyXB operation for appending a value to an XML node binding...

Comment: Please provide a minimilistic working example to demonstrate the problem. There is not much hope of solving your problem without seeing a full working example.

Comment: Yes I agree, but by the time I almost bundled a concise working example I realized the solution was of the same train of thought as xndrme's answer. My code is large, and so rather than give a lengthy explanation of it, suffice it to say you must always save a reference, especially of the absolute top-most-hierarchy-level widget (which was exactly what was missing in my case).

Comment: Yep, I thought that might turn out to be the case. The error you saw is generally always because you didn't save a reference somewhere where you should have. Glad you sorted it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually avoid that kind of errors keeping a reference on my class to all the objects susceptible of being deleted like your `QComboBox` so try something like `self.comboBoxHolder = QComboBox(...)` when you create it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm subclassing QComboBox. I think you're solution would work, but the issue isn't my subclass being deleted - its the underlying C object of which it extends... I tried this and it didn't work - still gave +1 though it was a good idea to test thanks again.

Comment: After trying to fabricate a concise working example per three_pineapples' recommendation, I realized your solution was the general answer to this problem; my QMainWindow (most top-level widget) was constructed and the reference to it was not saved as even a local variable. Literally I did QMainWindow().begin_rest_of_app(). All I needed was a simple: main = QMainWindow() and then main.begin_rest_of_app(). Thanks again.